# Template Metaprogramming for This?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

```
struct findCategoryByName
{
    string name;

    bool operator()(const category& a)
    {
        return (a.name == name);
    }
};

struct findEntryByName
{
    string name;

    bool operator()(const entry* a)
    {
        return (a->name == name);
    }
};
```

Is there a way to do this using template metaprogramming or something? I could always use a pointer to make it category* if that helps.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Search for one specific category or entry in a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a generic `findByName` template is as simple as replacing the specific type with a template parameter:

```
template<class T>
struct findByName
{
    string name;

    bool operator()(const T &a)
    {
        return (a.name == name);
    }
};
```

(This assumes the parameter is passed by reference, but you could change it to take a pointer as the parameter if you prefer.)